# Use of Modals "would" and imaginative situations

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Which of the following sentence is correct or both of them are correct?

> 1. If i were a bird, i had flown in the sky.
> 2. If i had been a bird, i had flown in the sky.

Also please tell how to express the imaginative past continuous situations.

example:

> 1. I would have carried my bag , if i were going to market.

I think the above sentence is incorrect after the "IF"  clause

Then what would be the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Which of the following sentence is correct or both of them are correct?**

**1.If i were a bird, i had flown in the sky.**

**2.If i had been a bird, i had flown in the sky.**

Neither of these are correct.  The correct formulation would be "If I were a bird, I would fly in the sky." This is for an imaginary present situation.  If you are looking for an imaginary past situation, the correct forumlation would be, "If I had been a bird, I would have flown in the sky."

**Also please tell how to express the imaginative past continuous situations.**

**example: **

**1.I would have carried my bag , if i were going to market.**

This should be expressed as, "I would have carried my bag if I had gone to the market."

EDIT:
Sorry, I misread your question for the last part. You are asking about imaginary past *continuous* situation. That case would be, "I would have been carrying my bag if I had been going to the market."